# UE4 cannot find gradle project

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, unreal-engine4

Have been following this URL for debugging my UE4 Android project ([Android debugging on Unreal](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/Android/AndroidDebugging/)). The documentation displays this kind of a folder structure

[image]

but upon packaging project from `File > Package Project > Android > Multi...`

this is the folder structure that gets generated which is completely different from the one displayed in the linked documentation for Android debugging on Unreal Engine. Has anyone experienced this issue before? Please can anyone describe how to export project in the correct manner? (note: the project is a blueprint project build on version 4.26)

[image]